# Compress huge JSON objects

Tags: rest, swagger

I get a huge JSON response from a REST API call. This causes my browser to freeze. I would like to prevent this freezing and show the complete JSON object.

Comment: What about *not* sending a huge response? Compression won't help here, that just cuts down on transmission time. When the client parses and expands it into JavaScript objects that's when you're suffering.

Comment: You've tagged this as Rust but the problem you've described manifests in a web browser. If you compress JSON on the server, it will still need to be decompressed and parsed in the browser, so that isn't going to help you. More likely, you could benefit from a streaming JSON parser on the client?

Comment: @PeterHall I will take a look about this, thanks.

Comment: When you say "this causes my browser to freeze", do you mean Swagger UI? Are you the developer of the API in question, or is it a third-party API?

Comment: What are you calling huge? The browser is freezing, but what are you doing with that data? Couldn't you just paginate the JSON ?